# Regex for identifying a string which determines users, values split by commas

Tags: javascript, regex

Each "User" is entered into my database as such:

```
First Name, Last Name, MIddle Name, email, [languages], [likes]
```

So an example entry would be:

```
John, Doe, Foo, johndoe@mail.com, [English, French], [Cars, Bikes]
```

I need a way to try and split this string so that I would get:

```
John
Doe
Foo
johndoe@mail.com
English, French
Cars, Bikes
```

My currently implementation uses string.split() and a regex for getting the contents in the square brackets, but I don't feel as if that is really a good way to go about things, because it's not really maintainable.

So I figure a regex to identify this would be great

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that each user will be separated by a semi-colon.

So for example:

```
John, Doe, Foo, johndoe@mail.com, [English, French], [Cars, Bikes];
Bob, M, Joe, bobjoe@mail.com, [English], [Bikes];
```

This will be counted as 2 different users

Comment: What happens if any of those fields contain a comma?

Comment: @Marty Which fields?

Comment: First name, last name, middle name, email, languages or likes.

Comment: Each value, i.e. First Name, Last Name, Middle Name, Email, Languages and Likes will all be primarily split by commas. The Languages and Likes will stay as a single piece, i.e. "English, French" and not "English", "French"

Comment: I mean if it's user-entered content they could potentially (even just for a laugh) make their first name `Mar,ty`.

Comment: Well if that's the case, then "ty" will be their last name I guess. This is mainly for inserting a huge list of users

Comment: *"The Languages and Likes will stay as a single piece, i.e. "English, French" and not "English", "French" "* how did you manage to keep the last two fields together if you are splitting by delimiter being a comma?

Comment: @zer00ne I think I wrote something wrong in that comment. When the whole giant string will be split, the languages should stay together in a single string. So there should ever be only a multiple of 6 "tokens" from this giant string.

Comment: EDIT: I kept them together because I am using some sort of for loop, where I take out the Languages and Likes first out of the string. Then I "tokenize" the remaining items. My code is really messy.

Comment: Are you generating the comma separated list currently? (in a for loop?) or is it provided in the format you're showing?

Comment: Nope. The context is that actual users can enter a bulk amount of data to the database, and they can do that by typing in these entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.replace()` with `RegExp` `/([^,\s\[\]]+)/ig` to surround string with quotes, `JSON.parse()` to create an array, concatenate newline character `"\n"` to string or `.join(", ")` call.

```js
var str = "John, Doe, Foo, johndoe@mail.com, [English, French], [Cars, Bikes]";
var arr = JSON.parse("[" + str.replace(/([^,\s\[\]]+)/ig, "\"$1\"") + "]");
let pre = document.querySelector("pre");
for (let prop of arr) {
  if (typeof prop === "string") {
    pre.textContent += prop + "\n";
  } else {
    pre.textContent += prop.join(", ") + "\n"
  }
}
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[^\s\[,;]+|\[([^\]]*)\]
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HTqg95/1)